# The effect of increasing the number of turns of a single layer coil on core flux

Tags: electromagnetism

I want to understand the effect of increasing the number of turns of a single layer coil on a iron core ,on the core flux, when fed from an fixed AC source of fixed frequency.

According to me , the flux should fall with an increase in number of turns...

Need help in understanding this concept.

Comment: When you say "current to fall square", I assume that you mean that the current will decrease by a factor of $1/N^2$. Is that what you mean? If so, why do you assume that will happen?

Comment: The current will fall by a factor of N^2 because inductive reactance (2*phi*f*L) will increase by N^2 since L is directly proportional to N ^2.

Comment: Current only falls if voltage and frequency are fixed.   You could just as easily fix current (and/or set frequency to zero).

Comment: Which means the voltage & frequency remaining constant,if the number turns of a stator coil of a motor is increased this will lead to lower flux??...so when designing a motor with high core flux , I need to reduce the number of turns of the coil in order that I get higher flux.

Comment: @joey I think you're right, and it is indeed an insightful question, in my opinion. However, your question could be cleaned up, by using some more precise language and equations and specifying that you are considering an AC voltage source. Also, are you assuming a single-layer coil? Because single-layer vs multi-layer windings affects the physics.

Comment: @led23head- I agree to what you suggested,but I am still waiting for the answer.Since I am an electrical engineer, I need to understand this to have a clear perception of design of motors when comes core flux , construction etc.

Comment: @joey My point is that you have a better chance at getting an answer if you edit your question to make it more clear. It took me a while to decipher what you meant. I think if you addressed some of the points in my previous comment, it will help. I personally don't have a complete answer for you at this point, but even with me it would help if you clarified some things.

Comment: @led23head- Absolutely....I am sorry for not giving full information so, here it is, a fixed AC voltage source with fixed frequency, single layer winding on an iron core.Need to know the effect on the flux in the core , when the number of turns of the coil is increased...

Comment: @joey Please edit the original question.

Comment: Any clue guys???...